# How to use path variable in post request in angular 7

Tags: angular, rest, http, http-post, path-variables

I am trying to send fileUrl to the rest Controller from angular post request. In post request i wanted to pass fileUrl as pathVariable.
Any idea to Post data using path variable in angular?

Answer (score -1):

"path variable" is part of URL. you can't put one url into another url. Sent it in BODY instead.
to do it with angular use httpClient

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

sendFileUrl(fileUrl: string) {
   return this.http.post('api/file', {fileUrl});
}
```

Comment: from my understanding he meant something like ```return this.http.get(`api/file?fileUrl=${fileUrl}`);```. And if its like that, usually u only do a GET request without a body.

Comment: is there any other way to pass path variable in post request with body?

Comment: "path variable" and "body" are different ways of passing data. "path variable" is part of url, while "body" is the content passed with the request. so the question is just contradictory